# Horizontal Stack labels in StackLayout that word warp

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am coding a Xamarin.Forms social networking app and am trying to make it so when I have multiple labels on one line they take up as much room as they need then the text of the next label and so forth.

Here is my attempted code

```
StackLayout bodyLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill 
};

Label word1 = new Label() { Text = "hey ppl you should follow" };
bodyLayout.Children.Add(word1);
Label word2 = new Label() { Text = "@SOCIALNETWORK" };
bodyLayout.Children.Add(word2);
Label word3 = new Label() { Text = "they are cool" };
bodyLayout.Children.Add(word3);
```

The result is this
[image: Code Result]

I would like it to print out as

> hey ppl you should follow @SOCIALNETWORK they are cool

and when it reaches the end of the screen it goes onto the next line

Comment: have you tried out all possible `LayoutOptions` options? It may be helpful if you use an xaml file and use the xamarin previewer

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use 3 labels?

Comment: @sme What this will be used for is adding support for hashtags, so I can split up a string looking for hashtags and make that one word (the hashtag) clickable

Comment: @Daniel Ok, makes sense now. I think it might be easier to create a custom label, and then use a custom renderer for each platform to be able to click on a given substring within the label. Using native Xamarin Forms controls and layouts, I don't think there is a way to accomplish what you need, so custom renderers will be needed in any event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Label.FormattedText and [Span](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Span/). There are a few limitations (most notably, no bindable properties on Span), but should work for what you want here:

```
Label line = new Label()
{
    FormattedText = new FormattedString()
    {
        Spans =
        {
            new Span() { Text = "hey ppl you should follow" },
            new Span() { Text = "@SOCIALNETWORK" },
            new Span() { Text = "they are cool" },
        }
    }
}
```